# How to make this slider script capable to show the exact image width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two scripts to show the top slider on my template:

```
    //Top slider script
    function FeaturedPostSide(a) {
        (function (e) {
            var h = {
                blogURL: "",
                MaxPost: 4,
                idcontaint: "",
                ImageSize: 100,
                interval: 5000,
                autoplay: false,
                loadingClass: "loadingxx",
                pBlank: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-htG7vy9vIAA/Tp0KrMUdoWI/AAAAAAAABAU/e7XkFtErqsU/s1600/grey.gif",
                MonthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                tagName: false
            };
            h = e.extend({}, h, a);
            var g = e(h.idcontaint);
            var d = h.MaxPost * 200;
            g.html('<div class="sliderx"><ul class="abt-sidebar-slider"></ul></div><div class="buttons"><a href="#" class="prevx">prev</a><a href="#" class="nextx">next</a></div>');
            var f = function (w) {
                var q,
                k,
                m,
                u,
                x,
                p,
                t,
                v,
                r,
                l = "",
                s = w.feed.entry;
                for (var o = 0; o < s.length; o++) {
                    for (var n = 0; n < s[o].link.length; n++) {
                        if (s[o].link[n].rel == "alternate") {
                            q = s[o].link[n].href;
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    if ("media$thumbnail" in s[o]) {
                        u = s[o].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s[0-9]+\-c/g, "/s" + h.ImageSize + "-c")
                    } else {
                        u = h.pBlank.replace(/\/s[0-9]+(\-c|\/)/, "/s" + h.ImageSize + "$1")
                    }
                    k = s[o].title.$t;
                    r = s[o].published.$t.substring(0, 10);
                    m = s[o].author[0].name.$t;
                    x = r.substring(0, 4);
                    p = r.substring(5, 7);
                    t = r.substring(8, 10);
                    v = h.MonthNames[parseInt(p, 10) - 1];
                    l += '<li><a target="_blank" href="' + q + '"><div class="overlayx"></div><img class="random" src="' + u + '"/><h4>' + k + '</h4></a><div class="label_text"><span class="date"><span class="dd">' + t + '</span> <span class="dm">' + v + '</span> <span class="dy">' + x + '</span></span> <span class="autname">' + m + "</span></div></li>"
                }
                e("ul", g).append(l).addClass(h.loadingClass)
            };
            var c = function () {
                e(h.idcontaint + " .nextx").click()
            };
            var b = function () {
                e.get((h.blogURL === "" ? window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host : h.blogURL) + "/feeds/posts/summary" + (h.tagName === false ? "" : "/-/" + h.tagName) + "?max-results=" + h.MaxPost + "&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script", f, "jsonp");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    e(h.idcontaint + " .prevx").click(function () {
                        e(h.idcontaint + " .sliderx li:first").before(e(h.idcontaint + " .sliderx li:last"));
                        return false
                    });
                    e(h.idcontaint + " .nextx").click(function () {
                        e(h.idcontaint + " .sliderx li:last").after(e(h.idcontaint + " .sliderx li:first"));
                        return false
                    });
                    if (h.autoplay) {
                        var i = h.interval;
                        var j = setInterval(c, i);
                        e(h.idcontaint + " .sliderx li:first").before(e(h.idcontaint + " .sliderx li:last"));
                        e(h.idcontaint + " .sliderx").hover(function () {
                            clearInterval(j)
                        }, function () {
                            j = setInterval(c, i)
                        })
                    }
                    e("ul", g).removeClass(h.loadingClass)
                }, d)
            };
            e(document).ready(b)
        })(jQuery)
    };
```

```
FeaturedPostSide({
    MaxPost: 3,
    idcontaint: "#featuredpostside",
    ImageSize: 600,
    interval: 5000, // speed up slider
    autoplay: false, // stop auto slider
    tagName: "Feature" // Feature is label name to display posts from it.
});
```

I used the above scripts to display the top slider, but

**The problem is that** the images show as stretched, or called it no perfect dimension  it has not the original size to display in top big slide, it show strech type.

[Screenshot 1](http://prntscr.com/a43dp0)

[Screenshot 2](http://prntscr.com/a43fya)

[Site Url](http://bolinaa.blogspot.com/)

Now what to do to get the best width and height dimension as the original image size, i hope there is something wrong at the first script, please help me anyone to get solve this issue. thanks.

**OR**

Give me a another script to add in template only for top slier images to show the width and height in exact dimension like you see in the screenshot the below images which show perfect dimension.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS problem easily set `height` to `auto`

```css
ul.abt-sidebar-slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

You can set `width` to `auto` too if you want the same width and height

Comment: i have added your style by firebug online, but then it comes like this: check this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/a43ran  it comes half, i need to display it as original image like you see in the screenshots' below images that i arrow. which has the perfect dimension to display.

Comment: its good, but its still need some customization to get accurate result, but its not a css customization to do that, its all about javascript, which can set natural image size to any frame...like you see still there is different between that both images...screenshot: http://prntscr.com/a44oev   i can set height for this to resize like that, but that is not the good approach, there is something done with java to get perfect dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Images are very hard to style correctly.
Can you try to use something like this:

```
<div class="image-container"></div>

.image-container {    
    height: desired height;
    width: desired width;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
    background: url('photo path');
}
```

Comment: this is not the case of css, i am well aware with css. its quite complicated to to with java. thanks for your views.

Answer (score 0):

I use a script like this to get the natural size of an image

```
var width;
var height
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function ()
{
    width = img.naturalWidth;
    height = img.naturalHeight;
}
img.src = "yourImagePath";
```

you can now keep the ratio easily...

```
ratio = width/height
```

Comment: where is the id or class so it only reflect the top slider images...because there are also many images on different places used in my template. so how to get that script for desired id or class to treat only those images. thanks.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean...you can get element by id or class like var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

Comment: @alexa, to for example: this is  <div id="wrapper"><img src="imagurl"></div> now to add your code, should i replace the img.src = "yourImagePath"; with my id wrapper ? or how to do that.

Comment: for that case                                                                                                         var src = document.getElementById("wrapper").childNodes[0].src;             will work you can check the fiddle here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rs77guo8/1/)

Comment: yours and microsmsm user latest update both helped me alot and i resolved the issue by your latest script and what he advised..thanks.

Comment: @Rajesh Surry Glad it help, you can accept an asnwer if it is resolved