# How to make this slider script capable to show the exact image width and height (not zoomed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I bought a template for my blog, and I experience the exact same issue described in this thread, wrote by the developer of my template:
[How to make this slider script capable to show the exact image width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439994/how-to-make-this-slider-script-capable-to-show-the-exact-image-width-and-height/39395274#39395274)

At the end of the post he apparently fixed the issue with the help of the community using this script on the link: 
https://jsfiddle.net/rs77guo8/1/
and this script :

```html
ul.abt-sidebar-slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

But unfortunately I am not a developer and I can't find out what part exactly I need to change in the code (and of course I tried to contact him several times without any results).

Would that be possible to be precise indicating me what lines I need to replace with what?

The top slider code in the template is in 2 parts. First:

```js
<script class='allscripters' type='text/javascript'>
      //<![CDATA[

//Top slider script
function FeaturedPostSide(a){(function(e){var h={blogURL:"",MaxPost:4,idcontaint:"",ImageSize:100,interval:5000,autoplay:false,loadingClass:"loadingxx",pBlank:"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-htG7vy9vIAA/Tp0KrMUdoWI/AAAAAAAABAU/e7XkFtErqsU/s1600/grey.gif",MonthNames:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],tagName:false};h=e.extend({},h,a);var g=e(h.idcontaint);var d=h.MaxPost*200;g.html('<div class="sliderx"><ul class="abt-sidebar-slider"></ul></div><div class="buttons"><a href="#" class="prevx">prev</a><a href="#" class="nextx">next</a></div>');var f=function(w){var q,k,m,u,x,p,t,v,r,l="",s=w.feed.entry;for(var o=0;o<s.length;o++){for(var n=0;n<s[o].link.length;n++){if(s[o].link[n].rel=="alternate"){q=s[o].link[n].href;break}}if("media$thumbnail" in s[o]){u=s[o].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s[0-9]+\-c/g,"/s"+h.ImageSize+"-c")}else{u=h.pBlank.replace(/\/s[0-9]+(\-c|\/)/,"/s"+h.ImageSize+"$1")}k=s[o].title.$t;r=s[o].published.$t.substring(0,10);m=s[o].author[0].name.$t;x=r.substring(0,4);p=r.substring(5,7);t=r.substring(8,10);v=h.MonthNames[parseInt(p,10)-1];l+='<li><a target="_blank" href="'+q+'"><div class="overlayx"></div><img class="random" src="'+u+'"/><h4>'+k+'</h4></a><div class="label_text"><span class="date"><span class="dd">'+t+'</span> <span class="dm">'+v+'</span> <span class="dy">'+x+'</span></span> <span class="autname">'+m+"</span></div></li>"}e("ul",g).append(l).addClass(h.loadingClass)};var c=function(){e(h.idcontaint+" .nextx").click()};var b=function(){e.get((h.blogURL===""?window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host:h.blogURL)+"/feeds/posts/summary"+(h.tagName===false?"":"/-/"+h.tagName)+"?max-results="+h.MaxPost+"&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script",f,"jsonp");setTimeout(function(){e(h.idcontaint+" .prevx").click(function(){e(h.idcontaint+" .sliderx li:first").before(e(h.idcontaint+" .sliderx li:last"));return false});e(h.idcontaint+" .nextx").click(function(){e(h.idcontaint+" .sliderx li:last").after(e(h.idcontaint+" .sliderx li:first"));return false});if(h.autoplay){var i=h.interval;var j=setInterval(c,i);e(h.idcontaint+" .sliderx li:first").before(e(h.idcontaint+" .sliderx li:last"));e(h.idcontaint+" .sliderx").hover(function(){clearInterval(j)},function(){j=setInterval(c,i)})}e("ul",g).removeClass(h.loadingClass)},d)};e(document).ready(b)})(jQuery)};

//]]>
    </script>
```

and second:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
FeaturedPostSide({
MaxPost:3,
idcontaint:"#featuredpostside",
ImageSize:600,
interval:5000,   // speed up slider
autoplay:false, // stop auto slider 
tagName:"Feature"  // Feature is label name to display posts from it.
});
</script>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Try reading comments from the question you linked. The snipped you pasted looks useless. The comments from the last answer indicate your developer resolved this issue so how comes it's still here half a year later? I'm sorry but your question shouldn't be posted here in the first place for various reasons. If you are not a developer, as a community we are unable and unwilling to help you here.

Comment: I already red every comments and tried to do it by myself using the comments but didn't succeed. I have no idea why he says it is resolved and it is still in the template he made me download last month... If you can't help, where should I ask?

Comment: I'd go to https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev.